# How to make a simple contact form input box responsive

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am learning how to make responsive sites..

I found a small/short contact form script that is sufficient for our needs.

The "message" input box on this is not responsive.

The active page is at http://qtest.pw

```
<div id="ContactWrapper">
<div id="ContactDiv1">  
<h2>Request an Appointment</h2>                 
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your phone number:<br>
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your request:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($phone=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
    else{       
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Appointment Request from Webpage for $name at $phone";
        mail("helmichfrontdesk@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Thank you for your Request. Your Email was sent! We will get back to you within one Business Day";
        }
    }  
?>
```

CSS

```
#ContactWrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1232px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
}
#ContactDiv1 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 46%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your form elements `width:100%`.

```
textarea{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: @CompStuff you got extra space on the right of your google map. is it necessary because it makes your page have scroll in smaller width. Put it on your CSS.

Comment: I tried <textarea style="width=100%" name="message" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea><br> AND IT WORKED.. Thanks

Comment: The space on the right is for directions once the address is submitted

Comment: @CompStuff is it necessary to place in on right? becoz it makes your page scrollable on smaller width.

Comment: It is a Dreamweaver map extension.. I will play with the CSS to get it to drop... Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay. Glad that I help.